# Could not load the file or assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

I have deployed a website on Virtual Machine with Windows server 2008 r2,iis 7 and .net framework 3.5.1 installed.

I have been getting the following error.

========================================

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 46:                <add assembly="stdole, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral , PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
Line 47:                <!--<add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>-->
Line 48:                <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" /></assemblies>
Line 49:        </compilation>
Line 50:     

Source File: C:\TFareDemo\web.config    Line: 48 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456
```

=========================================================
The application has features where excel reports are generated. I have not installed Office so i have been having trouble getting the website started.

1. I have tried many things like installing .net framework 1.1 redistributable package.
2. I have also installed Office Open XML as i read it somewhere that the problem might get solved.

Please help me with this.
My website is developed using vs 2005 and i do not have vs 2005 installed on the Virtual machine that i have mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

> I have not installed Office

You need to install MS Office (or at least Excel) on the machine executing your Excel handling code. It won't magically work without Excel.

Comment: It is a server machine so i wouldnt be allowed to install office on the server machine. I want it to work without installing Office.Is there any other solution?  I have also installed OpenOffice on the VM.

Comment: If you want to use Excel, you need to install Excel. You can use alternatives to Excel, then you will need to rewrite your program to use them and install those on your server.